# Nested Command in sed substitution

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed, ansible

I'm trying to used `sed` to find and encrypt `ansible_password` field in an inventory file and encrypt it with `ansible-vault` command. But `ansible-command` is failing throwing an `sed` error, where as a simple echo is working fine.

```
sed -n "s/\( *\)\(ansible_password\: *\)\"\(.*\)\"/$(echo \\3)/p" sample.yml
```

is outputting the attribute value without the double quotes.

The `ansible-vault` command:

```
sed -n "s/\( *\)\(ansible_password\: *\)\"\(.*\)\"/$(ansible-vault encrypt_string --vault-password-file ~/password.txt --name 'ansible_password' '\\3')/p" sample.yml
```

is throwing an error message: ``` sed: -e expression #1, char 67: unterminated ``s' command ```

Here's the line where the substitution is happening:

```
        ansible_password: "somepassword"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cannot work. The nested command will run first. `echo` works by accident because it will put `\3` as replacement pattern which happens to be what you want in this case (= output the original value).

Not sure what you exactly want, maybe you can try `grep` and `xargs`:

```bsh
grep -Po 'ansible_password: \K"[^"]*' sample.yaml \
| xargs -n1 ansible-vault encrypt_string --vault-password-file ~/password.txt --name 'ansible_password'
```

However, you might want to use a [proper `yaml` parser](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) instead of `grep` or  `sed`.

Comment: I'm trying to create a command which will replace an ansible inventory file's plain text password attribute with encrypted value

Comment: Yes, or more similar to what they were doing `ansible-vault encrypt_string --vault-password-file ~/password.txt --name 'ansible_password' "$(sed -rn "s/( *)(ansible_password\: *)\"(.*)\"/\3/p" sample.yml)"`

Comment: @MunavirChavody if your aim is to edit the file in place you could do something very inelegant like `sed -r "s/( *)(ansible_password\: *)\"(.*)\"/\1\2\""$(ansible-vault encrypt_string --vault-password-file ~/password.txt --name 'ansible_password' "$(sed -rn "s/( *)(ansible_password\: *)\"(.*)\"/\3/p" sample.yml)")"\"/" sample.yml`. Add the `-i` flag to the first `sed` if you see what you want (I hope the file is not very long). This works *because* the nested command runs first. I'm sure there's a nicer way though.

Comment: This actually solves my query. But the solution to my problem isn't going to be achievable using a single command.

Answer (score 3):

Use [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html#ansible-builtin-blockinfile-insert-update-remove-a-text-block-surrounded-by-marker-lines) if you can put the variables into the "# BEGIN ... # END" blocks, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat sample.yml
# BEGIN my_password1
my_password1: "somepassword1"
# END my_password1
# BEGIN my_password2
my_password2: "somepassword2"
# END my_password2
# BEGIN my_password3
my_password3: "somepassword3"
# END my_password3
```

Then the tasks below read the file and replace the blocks with encrypted variables, e.g.

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: sample.yml
        name: my_pswd
    - blockinfile:
        dest: sample.yml
        marker: "# {mark} {{ item }}"
        block: "{{ _enc }}"
      loop: [my_password1, my_password2, my_password3]
      vars:
        vault_cmd: "ansible-vault encrypt_string --name '{{ item }}' "
        _enc: "{{ lookup('pipe', vault_cmd ~  my_pswd[item]) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat sample.yml
# BEGIN my_password1
my_password1: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          30343161323861646333623332303663326438336462613165633766313130363961366633343764
          3335393837613638633565616366353139623063366131640a616233616534386663666263653432
          36376530653139666634323435313433346263643634303463643963343937316562326634313437
          6262613663313664630a343830636436376366656534366438613435366664656132643866353030
          3633
# END my_password1
# BEGIN my_password2
my_password2: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          36653034373863613531643535353361636565633463626465393065316561353661666564633762
          6139666336666433646633303664633261626135343865380a656464363430643563373264343234
          38303034653332626238326432333236333439383365623866656262343436386137353638663436
          3261363962373237300a646263396432646134313561366662326439303739303061303936353134
          6235
# END my_password2
# BEGIN my_password3
my_password3: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          31383764376166363733313065636264343863346334386230333739316337306535313866303164
          3465616663626565623438316364326532306538303134640a313564356135373931306236373833
          62383563386230633265396261363861393530653034613732333962643233316535646462656331
          6566383662323266310a343337303465613334336638316132636238343637646235646565653532
          6134
# END my_password3
```

When you repeat the tasks the encryption of the variables will be renewed.

Comment: I like this solution. But I have a handful of inventory files which I won't prefer to edit manually.

Comment: Try to automate the creation of the blocks. As a hint, see [mark-block.yml](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-config-light/blob/master/tasks/fn/mark-block.yml), YMMV.